# Python: TarFile.open No such file or directory

Tags: python, cygwin

So I'm fairly new to python and i'm writing a script that needs to untar a file. I use this simple function.

```
def untar(source_filename, dest_dir):
    for f in os.listdir():
        print(f)

    if(source_filename.endswith("tar.gz") or source_filename.endswith(".tar")):
        tar = tarfile.open(source_filename)
        tar.extractall(dest_dir)
        tar.close()
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not retrieve .depends for that file.")
```

I added the initial for loop for debugging purposes. When I invoke it, it prints out the name of the file i need in the current working directory meaning that it does exist. Here is the whole output.

```
 dep.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "init.py", line 70, in <module>
    untar('dep.tar.gz', ".")
  File "init.py", line 17, in untar
    tar = tarfile.open(source_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1548, in open
    return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1646, in bz2open
    compresslevel=compresslevel)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/bz2.py", line 102, in __init__
    self._fp = _builtin_open(filename, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dep.tar.gz'
```

Can someone tell me how it can see the file in the working directory, and then suddenly not be able to see the file in the working directory?

Comment: Have you tried with the absolute path for your dep.tar.gz file? How are you passing the dep.tar.gz filename source filename to your function?

Comment: the invocation is there in the output. untar('dep.tar.gz', ".") I'll try with absolute path

Comment: the absolute path to the file did not work either.

Comment: any chance there's a space at the beginning of the filename?  Unlikely but there is a space in the output

Comment: Your script works perfectly for me on a Mac. Is your dep.tar.gz file in the same directory that your init.py file?

Comment: Also, are you executing the init.py file on the same path it's located? This could be the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program I was using to create the tar placed a space at the beginning of the filename. So python was looking for 'dep.tar.gz' and the actual filename was ' dep.tar.gz'. ty @Ben

TIL - filenames can start with spaces.